# how can I reduce query depths using join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there are tables like these.

0. table t0

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 'a' |
| 101 | 'b' |
| 102 | 'c' |

1. table t1

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 8 | 101 |
| 9 | 102 |

2. table t2

| id | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 |

3. table t3

| id | base_id | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 |

4. table t4

| id | base_id | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 0 |
| 7 | 5 | 1 |

I wanna know all names of data whose flag is 1.
t3 is a sub table of t2, and t4 is a sub table of t3.
if the flag of super table's data is 1, sub table's flag is also 1 but not vice versa.

In this case, I  wrote the query statement like this.

```sql
select t1.id, t0.name from t0 join t1 on t0.user_id = t1.id where t1.id in 
  (select id from t2 where flag = 1 
   union 
   select base_id from t3 where flag = 1 or id in
     (select base_id from t4 where flag = 1)
  )
;
```

I think my query is not good enough, and I think there's a better way to do the task like reducing depths using join or etc.. but I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THAT....

Help me.. Is there some better way to do it?

Comment: Please describe the issue you are trying to solve. There are a lot of different ways to rewrite this query depending on cardinalities and presence of indexes for tables. But there's no obvious reason to rewrite it if it performs well.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like outer join (with condition that check flag value).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  t0 (user_id, name) as
  3    (select 100, 'a' from dual union all
  4     select 101, 'b' from dual union all
  5     select 102, 'c' from dual
  6    ),
  7  t1 (id, user_id) as
  8    (select 1, 100 from dual union all
  9     select 8, 101 from dual union all
 10     select 9, 102 from dual
 11    ),
 12  t2 (id, flag) as
 13    (select 1, 0 from dual union all
 14     select 8, 0 from dual union all
 15     select 9, 1 from dual
 16    ),
 17  t3 (id, base_id, flag) as
 18    (select 2, 1, 1 from dual union all
 19     select 5, 1, 0 from dual union all
 20     select 5, 2, 0 from dual
 21    ),
 22  t4 (id, base_id, flag) as
 23    (select 3, 2, 1 from dual union all
 24     select 4, 2, 1 from dual union all
 25     select 6, 5, 0 from dual union all
 26     select 7, 5, 1 from dual
 27    )
```

Query:

```
 28  select distinct t0.name
 29  from t0
 30    left join t1 on t1.user_id = t0.user_id
 31    left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
 32    left join t3 on t3.base_id = t2.id
 33    left join t4 on t4.base_id = t3.id
 34  where t2.flag = 1
 35     or t3.flag = 1
 36     or t4.flag = 1;

NAME
-----
a
c

SQL>
```

Comment: `left join t3 on t3.base_id = t2.id` should have `t1.id` instead of `t2.id` to be aligned with the original query. And `where` condition will be evaluated at the very end while it would be more optimal to push it inside table access and allow early filtering (for example, if there's only one row with `t2.flag = 1` and million od rows with `t2.flag = 0` and there's an index on this column then the original query will be way more optimal as it doesn't join what is not needed)

Comment: This may produce a different number of rows that the original query as there can be multiple rows in `t2`, `t3` or `t4` that have `flag = 1` and the OP's query uses `IN` to match any one of them to the outer query but this will match *all* of them to the outer query. You eliminate the duplicates using `DISTINCT` but this may eliminate duplicated expected rows (and is an additional overhead).

Comment: Also, you are missing `t1.id` from the outer `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

you could rewrite your query like this

```
 with
    t0 (user_id, name) as
    (select 100, 'a' from dual union all
       select 101, 'b' from dual union all
       select 102, 'c' from dual
      ),
    t1 (id, user_id) as
      (select 1, 100 from dual union all
       select 8, 101 from dual union all
      select 9, 102 from dual
     ),
   t2 (id, flag) as
     (select 1, 0 from dual union all
      select 8, 0 from dual union all
      select 9, 1 from dual
     ),
   t3 (id, base_id, flag) as
     (select 2, 1, 1 from dual union all
      select 5, 1, 0 from dual union all
     select 5, 2, 0 from dual
     ),
   t4 (id, base_id, flag) as
     (select 3, 2, 1 from dual union all
      select 4, 2, 1 from dual union all
      select 6, 5, 0 from dual union all
      select 7, 5, 1 from dual
     )
select t1.id, t0.name 
   from t0 join t1 on t0.user_id = t1.user_id
   JOIN   (select id from t2 where flag = 1 
   union 
   select t3.base_id from t3 
   JOIN t4 ON t3.id = t4.base_id  where t3.flag = 1 OR t4.flag = 1) t2a
   ON t1.id = t2a.id
```

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | c |
| 1 | a |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UApjXFGS)

But this would only be faster, if you have a lot of rows n your table

Comment: The last `JOIN` should have `OR` for both flags, not `AND`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it using `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t0.name
FROM   t0
       INNER JOIN t1
       ON (t0.user_id = t1.id)
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   t2
         WHERE  flag = 1 
         AND    t1.id = t2.id
       )
OR     EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   t3
         WHERE  t3.base_id = t1.id
         AND    (  flag = 1
                OR id IN (SELECT base_id FROM t4 WHERE flag = 1)
                )
       );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t0.name
FROM   t0
       INNER JOIN t1
       ON (t0.user_id = t1.id)
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   t2
         WHERE  flag = 1 
         AND    t1.id = t2.id
       )
OR     EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   t3
                LEFT OUTER JOIN t4
                ON (t3.id = t4.base_id AND t4.flag = 1)
         WHERE  t3.base_id = t1.id
         AND    (t3.flag = 1 OR t4.flag = 1)
       );
```